# Deductive closure of sentence $\forall x \forall y F(x,y) \stackrel{.}{=} F(y,x)$ in language $\mathcal{L}$ is undecidable.

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

$\mathcal{L}$ is the language that contains a single binary function symbol $F$. In the earlier parts of this question, we were told to take the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ with universe $\omega$ (non-negative integers) and the interpretation of $F$ as $F(x,y) = (x+y)^2$.

From Tarski's theorem on strongly undecidable structures, I figured that all I needed to do was to show that the standard model is defined by this model. I was able to show that $\mathcal{M}$ defines the constants 0 and 1, the addition of non-negative integers $(+)$, and the multiplication of non-negative integers $(\cdot)$.

What I don't understand is how the deductive closure of a sentence might change the decidability of the language? My understanding of strongly undefinable structures is that no matter what sentence I add to it, I can always find another that is independent of the axioms. Am I right?

If I'm not, please enlighten me. I only have basic understanding of model theory and predicate logic, and I'm now studying the incompleteness theorems. If there are any good resources where I can read more about this, please share! Thank you!

Comment: Your question isn't clear about the statement of the problem you are trying to solve. The theory of your two-place arithmetic function $f$ is certainly undecidable and you are doing the right thing to prove that by showing that the language of arithmetic can be interpreted in it. A "strongly undecidable structure" is a structure $M$ for some signature $\Sigma$ with the property that any theory over $\Sigma$ that has $M$ as a model is undecidable. Google will find you some more information about strong undecidable structures and theories.

Comment: Also, adding an axiom to a theory can make it decidable.E.g., the theory of abelian groups is decidable but the theory of groups in general is not. In this case, the axiom you are adding looks rather odd though because in the ${\cal L}$-structure you are interested in, it is already true. However, theories like Robinson's $Q$ or $PA$ have no consistent decidable extensions.